# Check if function alias exists

Tags: java, h2, user-defined-functions

My goal is to register a user defined function in h2. The second time I execute the program an error, stating that my function alias already exists, appears.

```
stmt.execute("CREATE ALIAS LEVENSHTEIN FOR
 \"modules.musicProvider.LocalNetworkMusicProvider.computeLevenshteinDistance\"");
```

After taking a look at INFORMATION_SCHEMA, I can't find a way to check beforehand if the function is already defined or not.

1. How do figure out if a user defined function is already defined?
2. How do I delete user defined functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is a bit of an old question, but as I have been working with H2 today in this exact area of user-defined functions I thought I would answer the question.

One option is to always drop the `ALIAS` before creating it:

```
DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS LEVENSHTEIN;
```

I got this information from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718865/stored-procedure-in-h2-database).

Another other option is to not create the alias if it already exists:

```
CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS LEVENSHTEIN ...
```

I got this nugget from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942779/why-doesnt-my-alias-show-up-in-information-schema-function-aliases) and [the H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_alias).

Finally, you can also execute this query to see if the `ALIAS` exists:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FUNCTION_ALIASES WHERE ALIAS_NAME = 'LEVENSHTEIN')
```

I got the basics for this query from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942779/why-doesnt-my-alias-show-up-in-information-schema-function-aliases).